# Efficiently process records in mongodb in single machine

Tags: mongodb, performance, apache-spark, optimization

I have big dataset in mongodb to process. Sometime we only have one machine.

For example,

1. Have 1 million records in mongodb collection A. Data size is about 60GB .
2. Only one machine 4 core , 24G ram,  mongodb in this machine too.
3. Only HDD no SSD.
4. Every record has html need parse , and regex match .
5. Result need insert to another collection B

Because point 4 , mongodb built-in mapreduce can't be competent . And I also tend to use python.

I do some testing and find :

1. if skip is large, query would be very slow

   ```
   cursor = collection.find({'result.type':'detail'}, skip=start, limit=start+PRODUCER_CHUNKS)
   ```
2. With collection B record increasing, insert performance slow down much.

Any setting can improve above?

Besides, would it be faster if I deploy a docker spark cluster in this machine to do same job?
Because there is only one machine, so I think the most efficiently way is use `multiprocessing` . I implement this , but the speed is 25 record per second, I think it still slow .

---

### Update

In my thought,

1. HHD write speed is over 120MB/s, I think it is enough to do such things ?
2. per record size is 60*1024*1024/10^6 = 62kb ,  25record/s * 62kb /1024 = 1.5MB/s ,  much much lower than 120MB/s
3. One producer, Four workers(non-blocking, use asyncio) , each run in different process. CPU is E1231V3 .
4. Queue size is 500, easily full if collection B became large (because workers take the responsibility write to collection B , and insertion keep slowing down while processing. )

I think maybe has some way to speed up like if the limitation is memory:

1. db split my data in parts,  maybe 60GB /5GB  = 12
2. db use 5GB ram cache to read
3. db use 5GB ram cache to write (like redis, some interval write write once .  mongodb has memory only mode,however it doesn't persist.)

Comment: There is no way around lack of hardware. Your data size is 2.5x your RAM, and apparently your query touches every document in that collection. Since your RAM is small, MongoDB would have to load the documents from the database. Since you use spinning disk, this will be even slower. Skipping won't help in your case, since it looks like your criteria (`{'result.type': 'detail'}`) does not have high enough cardinality. Running things on docker on the same machine would just add another layer requiring an already-strained resources.

Comment: @Kevin Adistambha HDD is not that slow, please see my update,  .

Comment: Spark has to load and process/store data in the same RAM as Mongo. Disk isn't necessary the  limit here

Comment: @cricket_007 Read is not the limitation. I just express `skip` `limit` would make read slow .   I think the problems are  process speed(html to text, regex match) and insertion . I mention spark  because I think it may process faster than a python program.

Comment: You may be able to split the work into batches, but I'm not convinced that it will lower the overall processing time. I don't think using parallel processing will help much since I believe the bottleneck here is disk, not CPU. Unfortunately with the hardware you have, I don't see anything that can provide a dramatic speed increase. I tend to think that using SSD will speed things up a bit since it will require less time to read/write data.

Comment: I'm only here for the Spark tag, but it's limited by the JVM itself which has additional overhead. Have you tried writing a PyMongo process?

Comment: @cricket_007 What do you mean `PyMongo process`, does that mean start a custom pymongo process to manage memory usage ?  My menory never full. I think pymongo already do insertion efficiently ---  bulk insert . Actually I init a motor(async pymongo) connection in each process. I do bulk insert if record number hit 500 in each worker.

Comment: No... I simple mean, what have you tried already that's convinced you that multiprocessing is necessary? You've only shown one line of code here